# How do I use functions defined with Func in the solve function?

Tags: function, calculator, ti-basic, ti-nspire

Say I have this function defined using `Func`:

```
Define f(x)=Func
              Return x²
            EndFunc
```

I can use this function in most cases perfectly fine:

```
f(2)            © 4
f(3)+f(4)       © 24
cos(f(sqrt(π))) © -1
expand(f(x+1))  © x²+2⋅x+1
```

However, when I try to use this function in `solve` or `cSolve` (possibly some other functions as well), it doesn't work as expected:

```
© I expected 'x=-2 or x=2'
solve(f(x)=4,x)   © f(x)=4
© I expected 'x=-2⋅i or x=2⋅i'
cSolve(f(x)=-4,x) © f(x)=-4
```

It doesn't seem to expand/evaluate the function call and leaves it as `f(x)`.

On the other hand, if I don't use `Func`, it works perfectly fine:

```
Define g(x)=x²   © Done
solve(g(x)=4,x)  © x=-2 or x=2
cSolve(g(x)=4,x) © x=-2⋅i or x=2⋅i
```

`nSolve` works for both `f` and `g` as intended, so this makes me think it's something to do with symbolic computations.

- Is there any documentation about this difference? I've looked over the relevant sections of the reference guide and the guidebook, but have found nothing.
- Is there a way of defining functions using `Func` (so I can use local variables and things like that) that still work with functions like `solve` and `cSolve`?

I'm using a TI-Nspire CX CAS Handheld (the older one, not the CX II).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted customer support and they responded with

> There is not a way to use the function defined the way you did using "func" and "return" with the solve command.